# Using Authorize.Net SDK in Laravel 5.1 via composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorize.net

What is the best practice when using third-party SDKs with Laravel?

After loading Authorize.net SDK via composer like so...

```
composer require authorizenet/authorizenet:~1.8
```

Do I need to add AuthorizeNet class to providers list in /config/app.php

What needs to be added specifically and how to make class work in controller?

I'm trying to add
    `Authorizenet\AuthorizeNetARB::class, to /config/app.php`
and 
    `use Authorizenet\AuthorizeNetARB;`
to my controller but getting this error:
        FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
        Class 'Authorizenet\AuthorizeNetARB' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't need to add it to your `config/app.php` because it's not a **Laravel**-package.

You can directly use `AuthorizeNetARB` because it's [not namespaced.](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/blob/dad03528bd446adffd6cb0e75d62fe20dd1140ed/lib/AuthorizeNetARB.php)

```
$example = New \AuthorizeNetARB();
```

Comment: Got it, but I'm getting 
    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthorizeNetARB' not found

Comment: Either use `New \AuthorizeNetARB()` or import the namespace `use AuthorizeNetARB `

Comment: Thank you! Just when I thought I tried everything... This works: `$request = new \AuthorizeNetARB;`